# Align a TD to the right of the TABLE

Tags: html, alignment, row, html-table

Lets say that I've got 3 columns, 1 row. I want to have the first column as big as it can get, without making the other columns content to jump down a line(as if there were a linebreak). Like this:

|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| |||||||||||||||||||| ||||||||||||||||||||||

So the first column should use as much sapace as it can from the table without making any problem for the other two column which should just use as much space they need and nothing more and they should be aligned to the right.

I tried using a set width for it, but as the content of the two last columns rise it creates a problem which force the text to jump down a line.

How can I make this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the main cell width="100"%" and add "nowrap" to the other cells.

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>           
        <td width="100%">###</td>
        <td nowrap>### ###### ###</td>
        <td nowrap>###### ###### ###</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I add the nowarp? Thanks!

Comment: style for nowrap is `white-space: nowrap`

Comment: @ZyteX: works for me. there must be something else on your page that is interfering. Maybe another style. Try this in a clean HTML file.

Comment: There are limitations - how much text do you have in there?

Comment: Well, i stand by my last comment.